# Procedure to obtain copy of Window 7 DVD and retrieve misplaced product key

Tags: windows-7

I have misplaced my Windows 7 (with SP1) DVD and the product key. I want to upgrade to Windows 10 but I think I cannot do so without the above two things.

1. Is there a way I can obtain the Windows 7 DVD?
2. Also can I retrieve the product key?

Comment: All Windows 7 devices are required to have the COA sticker on them.  This COA sticker will have the license printed on them.   If your license is not a OEM license update your question to make the specific.

Answer (score 1):

If your PC already has Windows 7 installed and activated, you do not need the Windows 7 DVD or the product key to upgrade.

If your Windows version was any edition of Windows 7 other than Enterprise:

1. Just go ahead and run Windows Update. It will display an icon in your Notification bar asking you if you want to upgrade to Windows 10. Click yes. It will download the Windows 10 files and automatically activate Windows 10.

OR

2. If you do not want to do that, download a trail copy of Windows 10 (Home if you had Windows 7 Starter, Home Basic or Home Premium else Pro) Insert the DVD and run the setup. The setup will validate your activation of Windows 7 and upgrade and activate to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DVD and product key, its a retail copy. In this day and age, its suprisingly trivial to get these if the install's still working.

I'd actually done this on one of my old systems, though obviously you can swap around the tools as needed.

step 1 Retrieve the key. At the *moment* I favour nirsoft's [produkey](http://nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html). I'm pretty certain OEM installs have a generic key that's useless, unless you installed off the sticker key at some point

step 2 go to [windows product recovery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/home), pick your version and download the media. This is the *official* way to do this and gives you a *legitimate* **current** release of windows of the version you picked.

step 3 You could burn this into a dvd but this is wasteful. And there's an official tool for this [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) . *However* I favour [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). Its cleaner, simpler and more flexible, and I use it with everything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Microsoft has the download for Windows ten, however the first few things it says is "you need your product key to continue"